# Blazor Webassembly project calling REST API

Tags: rest, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor WebAssembly application and tried calling an external weather API for testing purposes. I put an XUnit test project in front of the WeatherService class that I created and the test execute successfully giving me the data.

When I run it from a Blazor component I see in the F12 developer tools console that the REST call executed.

[image]

But I see a bunch of errors in the Console.
[image]

It does not load the data on the page as expected. Has anyone faced this situation. I am running the latest template of the Blazor App built using VS 2019.

Also my Blazor Web Assembly app is not hitting any breakpoints, so I dont really know at what stage it is breaking.

Comment: We cannot help you without the code.

Comment: _"I put an XUnit test project in front of the WeatherService class"_ is a little vague. Apparently it doesn't work.

Comment: I think we need to at least see where/when your making the async request to the API.